# Index out of Range in consumer Thread

Tags: python, multithreading, synchronization, producer-consumer

I have a Thread that should wait for tasks to arrive from different multible Threads and execute them until no task is left. If no task is left it should wait again.

I tried it with this class (only relevant code):

```
from threading import Event, Thread

class TaskExecutor(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.event = Event()
        self.taskInfos = []
        self._running = True

        task_thread = Thread(target=self._run_worker_thread)
        self._running = True
        task_thread.daemon = True
        task_thread.start()

    def _run_worker_thread(self):
        while self.is_running():
            if len(self.taskInfos) == 0:
                self.event.clear()
                self.event.wait()

            try:
                msg, task = self.taskInfos[0]
                del self.taskInfos[0]
                if task:
                    task.execute(msg)
            except Exception, e:
                logger.error("Error " + str(e))

    def schedule_task(self, msg, task):
        self.taskInfos.append((msg, task))
        self.event.set()
```

Multiple Threads are calling `schedule_task` everytime they like to add a task.

The problem is that I get an error sometimes saying: `list index out of range` from the `msg, task = self.taskInfos[0]` line. The `del self.taskInfos[0]` below is the only one where I delete a task.

How can that happen? I feel like I have to `synchronize` everything, but there is no such keyword in python, and reading the docs brought up this pattern.

Comment: I think you should re-check for `len(self.taskInfos) > 0` after the `...wait() ...` cause the thread can resume with the condition `len(self.taskInfos) == 0` in `True`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code is pretty hopeless - give up on it and do something sane ;-)  What's sane?  Use a `Queue.Queue`.  That's designed to do what you want.

Replace:

```
    self.event = Event()
    self.taskInfos = []
```

with:

```
    self.taskInfos = Queue.Queue()
```

(of course you have to `import Queue` too).

To add a task:

```
    self.taskInfos.put((msg, task))
```

To get a task:

```
    msg, task = self.taskInfos.get()
```

That will block until a task is available.  There are also options to do a non-blocking `.get()` *attempt*, and to do a `.get()` attempt with a timeout (read the docs).

Trying to fix the code you have would be a nightmare.  At heart, `Event`s are not powerful enough to do what you need for thread safety in this context.  In fact, any time you see code doing `Event.clear()`, it's *probably* buggy (subject to races).

**Edit:  what will go wrong next**

If you continue trying to fix this code, this is likely to happen next:

```
the queue is empty
thread 1 does len(self.taskInfo) == 0, and loses its timeslice
thread 2 does self.taskInfos.append((msg, task))
         and does self.event.set()
         and loses its timeslice
thread 1 resumes and does self.event.clear()
         and does self.event.wait()
```

Oops!  Now thread 1 waits forever, despite that a task *is* on the queue.

That's why Python supplies `Queue.Queue`.  You're exceedingly unlikely to get a correct solution using a feeble `Event`.

Comment: I've done exactly that, but find myself in a Deadlock after first call to `msg, task = self.taskInfos.get()`. The code will never advance this line, even tasks are put inside the Queue.

Comment: Then **show your code** in a new question.  Many thousands of people use `Queue` every day without any problems.  So, believe it or not, chances are very good that you're confused about something ;-)  But nobody can guess about *what* from that tiny English description.

Comment: already on the way. If you're interested: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20508479/deadlock-because-of-blocking-queue-get-method

Answer (score 2):

The following sequence is possible (assume *Thread #0* is a consumer and runs your `_run_worker_thread` method, and threads *Thread #1* and *Thread #2* are producers and call `schedule_task` method):

- Thread #0 waits on the event, queue is empty
- Thread #1 calls `schedule_task` and **is preempted before `set`**
- Thread #2 calls `schedule_task` and reaches `set`
- Thread #0 awakens and does **two** iterations, clearing the task queue
- Thread #1 awakens and reaches the `set` call
- Thread #0 awakens with incorrect state - the queue is empty

The parts in bold are key to understand the race that is possible. Basically, the worker thread can consume all the tasks, spinning with `if len(self.taskInfos) == 0` condition being `False` before all producers will manage to `set` the event after appending to the queue.

Possible solutions include checking the condition again after `wait` as suggested in the comments by [xndrme](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2997574/xndrme), or using the [`Lock`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#lock-objects) class, best one probably being the `Queue.Queue` class mentioned by [Tim Peters](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2705542/tim-peters) in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20502786/2642204).

Comment: Agreed, except it would be better for the OP to use a `Queue` than continue creating new implementations of `Queue` with ever-subtler bugs ;-)

Comment: @TimPeters You're right :) I've added a link to your answer, it's probably the best solution.