# deadlock because of blocking Queue.get() method

Tags: python, python-2.7, queue, multiprocessing, producer-consumer

As the title implies I have a deadlock and no idea why. I have multiple producers and only one consumer. The `schedule_task` method will get called by multiple processes after the thread has called the `get` method of the queue

```
from logging import getLogger
from time import sleep
from threading import Event, Thread
from multiprocessing import Process
from Queue import Queue


class TaskExecutor(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print("init taskExecutor")
        self.event = Event()
        self.taskInfos = Queue()
        task_thread = Thread(target=self._run_worker_thread)
        self._instantEnd = False
        self._running = True
        task_thread.daemon = True
        task_thread.start()

    def _run_worker_thread(self):
        print("start running taskExcecutor worker Thread")
        while self.is_running():
            try:
                print("try to get queued task from %s" % str(self.taskInfos))
                msg, task = self.taskInfos.get()
                print("got task %s for msg: %s" % str(task), str(msg))
                task.execute(msg)
                self.taskInfos.task_done()
            except Exception, e:
                logger.error("Error: %s" % e.message)
        print("shutting down TaskExecutor!")

    def is_running(self):
        return True

    def schedule_task(self, msg, task):
        try:
            print("appending task '%s' for msg: %s" % (str(task), str(msg)))
            self.taskInfos.put((msg, task))
            print("into queue: %s " % str(self.taskInfos))
        except Exception, e:
            print("queue is probably full: %s" % str(e))


class Task(object):

    def execute(self, msg):
        print(msg)


executor = TaskExecutor()

def produce():
    cnt = 0
    while True:
        executor.schedule_task("Message " + str(cnt), Task())
        cnt += 1
        sleep(1)

for i in range(4):
    p = Process(target=produce)
    p.start()
```

From my logs I get:

```
init taskExecutor
start running taskExcecutor worker Thread
try to get queued task from <Queue.Queue instance at 0x7fdd09830cb0>
 appending task '<__main__.Task object at 0x7fdd098f8f10>' for msg: Message 0
into queue: <Queue.Queue instance at 0x7fdd09830cb0> 
appending task '<__main__.Task object at 0x7fdd098f8f10>' for msg: Message 0
into queue: <Queue.Queue instance at 0x7fdd09830cb0> 
appending task '<__main__.Task object at 0x7fdd098f8f10>' for msg: Message 0
into queue: <Queue.Queue instance at 0x7fdd09830cb0> 
appending task '<__main__.Task object at 0x7fdd098f8f10>' for msg: Message 0
into queue: <Queue.Queue instance at 0x7fdd09830cb0> 
appending task '<__main__.Task object at 0x7fdd086f35d0>' for msg: Message 1
into queue: <Queue.Queue instance at 0x7fdd09830cb0> 
appending task '<__main__.Task object at 0x7fdd086f3490>' for msg: Message 1
into queue: <Queue.Queue instance at 0x7fdd09830cb0> 
appending task '<__main__.Task object at 0x7fdd086f3b10>' for msg: Message 1
into queue: <Queue.Queue instance at 0x7fdd09830cb0> 
appending task '<__main__.Task object at 0x7fdd086f3b10>' for msg: Message 1
into queue: <Queue.Queue instance at 0x7fdd09830cb0>
```

Can someone please explain, what am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While it's not possible for other people to run this code (it's not self-contained), there's no obvious problem in *what you showed*.  So the problem is in something you *haven't* showed - perhaps in the code creating and using instances of `TaskExecutor`.

And when I plugged in missing pieces I made up out of thin air, this code worked fine.

So you need to show more than just this.  How about replacing:

```
logger.debug("try to get queued task")
```

with

```
logger.debug("try to get queued task from queue %s", self.taskInfos)
```

?  Then at least we could see whether your producers are using *the same* queue as your consumer.

**Next**

Thanks for adding that.  Next up:  here's a self-contained program for you to try.  It's very much like your code.  See whether it runs correctly for you (it does for me):

```
from threading import Thread, Lock
from Queue import Queue

class Logger:
     def __init__(self):
         self.iolock = Lock()

     def debug(self, str, *msg):
         with self.iolock:
             print str % msg

     error = debug

logger = Logger()

class TaskExecutor(object):
    def __init__(self):
        logger.debug("init taskExecutor")
        self.taskInfos = Queue()
        task_thread = Thread(target=self._run_worker_thread)
        task_thread.daemon = True
        task_thread.start()

    def is_running(self):
        return True

    def _run_worker_thread(self):
        logger.debug("start running taskExcecutor worker Thread")
        while self.is_running():
            try:
                logger.debug("try to get queued task from queue %s", self.taskInfos)
                msg, task = self.taskInfos.get()
                logger.debug("got task %s for msg: %s", str(task), str(msg))
                #task.execute(msg)
                self.taskInfos.task_done()
            except Exception, e:
                logger.error("Error: %s", e.message)
        logger.debug("shutting down TaskExecutor!")

    def schedule_task(self, msg, task):
        try:
            logger.debug("appending task '%s' for msg: %s", str(task), str(msg))
            self.taskInfos.put((msg, task))
            logger.debug("into queue: %s ", str(self.taskInfos))
        except Exception, e:
            logger.debug("queue is probably full: %s", str(e))

te = TaskExecutor()

def runit():
    for i in range(10):
        te.schedule_task("some task", i)

main = Thread(target=runit)
main.start()
```

**Next**

OK, this code can't possibly work.  On a Linux-y system, exactly one instance of `TaskExecutor` is created, here:

```
executor = TaskExecutor()
```

That happens in the main program.  Each time you do:

```
p = Process(target=produce)
```

your main program is `fork()`'ed.  While the forked processes also see `executor`, that's an address-space **copy** of the main program's `executor`, and has nothing whatsoever to do with the `executor` in the main program (the usual copy-on-write `fork()` semantics).

Each child process also has a **copy** of `executor`'s data members, including its `Queue`.  All the child processes put data on their own unique copy of `executor`, but the consumer thread is running *only* in the main program, and *nothing* worker processes do to their copy of `executor` can have any effect on what the main program's consumer thread sees.

So this is really confused.  I have to stop now to try to figure out what you might *really* want to be doing here ;-)  If you want to play with ideas, investigate using a `multiprocessing.Queue`.  The **only** way to communicate between processes is to use objects that are built from the ground up to support inter-process communication.  `Queue.Queue` will never work for that.

**And one more**

Here's one that works fine across processes, and even on Windows ;-)

```
from time import sleep
from threading import Thread
from multiprocessing import Process, JoinableQueue

class TaskExecutor(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        print("init taskExecutor")
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.taskInfos = JoinableQueue()

    def getq(self):
        return self.taskInfos

    def run(self):
        print("start running taskExcecutor worker Thread")
        while self.is_running():
            try:
                print("try to get queued task from %s" % self.taskInfos)
                msg, task = self.taskInfos.get()
                print("got task %s for msg: %s" % (task, msg))
                task.execute(msg)
                self.taskInfos.task_done()
            except Exception, e:
                print("Error: %s" % e.message)
        print("shutting down TaskExecutor!")

    def is_running(self):
        return True

class Task(object):
    def execute(self, msg):
        print(msg)

def produce(q):
    cnt = 0
    while True:
        q.put(("Message " + str(cnt), Task()))
        cnt += 1
        sleep(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    executor = TaskExecutor()
    executor.start()
    for i in range(4):
        p = Process(target=produce, args=(executor.getq(),))
        p.start()
```

The if `__name__ == "__main__"` part doesn't just allow it to run on Windows, it has great "documentation" value too, making it obvious at a glance that `executor` indeed runs *only* in the main program.

A question for you is whether this is the division of labor you want, though.  Do you really want the main process - and only the main process - to do all the

```
   task.execute(msg)
```

work?  No way from here to guess whether that's what you want.  That is what the code does.

Style point:  note that this gets rid of the `schedule_task()` method.  Parallel processing can be difficult, and over the decades I've found it extremely valuable to keep inter-thread/inter-process communication as simple and dead obvious as possible.  That means, among other things, making use of message queues directly instead of, e.g., hiding them in methods.  Layers of abstraction in this context often makes correct code *harder* to create, extend, debug and maintain.

Comment: I checked, yours and it works obviously. So I made my own self-containing example. Maybe you can check that

Comment: Thank you! I really didn't know whether it would work for you, so I'm glad you tried it.  For example, maybe you have a corrupted version of `Queue.py`, etc etc etc - just being methodical here ;-)

Comment: Ah, this is *infinitely* more complicated than you said at the start:  you're not just playing with threads, you're trying to communicate across *processes* too.  Next:  which operating system are you using?  Your code won't run at all on, e.g., Windows.

Comment: arch linux latest update python 2.7, and I said, that `processes` are calling `schedule_task`.

Comment: thx for your time to investigate. Really confusing to think of the queues as different objects because it seems they have the same address in memory (0x7fdd09830cb0 in the above case). I will think about a solution and post a new question if it doesn't work again :)

Comment: That's what `fork()` does:  creates an exact copy of the forked program, even (usually) with the same virtual addresses.  Mixing `fork()` with threads has killed more programmers than it has saved ;-)

Comment: BTW, note that ah "%s" format code automatically invokes `str()` - no need to keep calling `str()` yourself everywhere in `print` calls.